# Extracting data from url in rails using Ajax and Nokogiri

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't know what's wrong with this code. I want to get data from the url and display them when the user paste that url into the textbox. Here is my code:

app/assets/javascripts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#post_content").bind('paste', function(e) {

      var el = $(this);

      setTimeout(function() {
          var text = $(el).val();

          // send url to service for parsing
          $.ajax('/links/linkpreview', {
              type: 'POST',
              data: { url: text },
              success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR ) {
                  // handle received data
                  $("#preview-title").text(data['title']);
              },
              error: function() { alert("error"); }
          });
      }, 100);
  });

});
```

app/controllers/links_controller.rb:

```
def linkpreview
  url = params[:url]
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url), nil, 'UTF-8')

  title = ""
  description = ""
  url = ""
  image_url = ""

  doc.xpath("//head//meta").each do |meta|
      if meta['property'] == 'og:title'
          title = meta['content']
      elsif meta['property'] == 'og:description' || meta['name'] == 'description'
          description = meta['content']
      elsif meta['property'] == 'og:url'
          url = meta['content']
      elsif meta['property'] == 'og:image'
          image_url = meta['content']
      end
  end

  if title == ""
      title_node = doc.at_xpath("//head//title")
      if title_node
          title = title_node.text
      elsif doc.title
          title = doc.title
      else
          title = param_url
      end
  end

  if description ==""
      #maybe search for content from BODY
      description = title
  end

  if url ==""
      url = param_url
  end

  render :json => {:title => title, :description => description, :url => url, :image_url => image_url} and return

end
```

app/views/links/_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :url %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :url, class: "form-control", id: "post_content" %>
</div>
<div id="preview-title"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if post request is correctly send from browser by chrome development tool.
2. Check if rails app is correctly receiving request from app log.
3. Check if rails app is correctly sending response.
4. Check if the browser is correctly receiving response.

Comment: I'm new to rails and don't fully understand Ajax, can you show me where is the problem and why my code doesn't work?

Comment: I don't find any problem by reading codes. So please check the list or paste JavaScript console log and rails app log. If you don't know how, please ask.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the route.rb to  match "links/linkpreview" => "links#linkpreview", :via => [:post], :as => "links/linkpreview" and it works! :))

Comment: And another thing is that I have to add "require 'open-uri'" to linkpreview action for these codes to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error in Javascript console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/links/linkpreview 404 (Not Found)
```

And here is the log message:

```
tarted POST "/links/linkpreview" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-08 17:59:03 +0700
```

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/links/linkpreview"):
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:22:in `middleware_call'
  web-console (2.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in`call_app'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in`tagged'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in`call'
  activesupport (4.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in`call'
  actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in`call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call'
  rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
  /home/tuong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`service'
  /home/tuong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/tuong/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in`block in start_thread'

Rendered /home/tuong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered /home/tuong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/web-console-2.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.text.erb (3.5ms)